# auto padding in JSF

Tags: css, jsf-2, padding

I have a PanelGrid with 2 cells (Left and right). Its a big panelgrid and in left cell i have a little text, so i have a big cell and in the center a minimal text. In the right one i have a  inputTextArea. When i want to set a background for the left cell, its only afected around the text and all the cell still without colour. I used the paddings (setting the number of pixels) options to adjust the cell background.
The problem is the InputTextArea. When you resize the text area the cells are resized too but the padding of the left cell no. Ss there any option that it isnt necesary to set the padding pixels and when i resize the cell, the color of background too?.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the background color to span the entire cell, you'd need to set it on the cell itself instead of the cell's contents.

```html
<h:panelGrid column="2" columnClasses="leftColumn,rightColumn">
    <h:outputText />
    <h:inputTextarea />
</h:panelGrid>
```

wherein you specify the background color in `leftColumn` class.

An alternative is to make the cell contents a block element instead of an inline element so that its size spans the entire cell. E.g. by making it a `<div>`

```html
<h:panelGrid column="2">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="redBackground">
        <h:outputText value="some" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputTextarea />
</h:panelGrid>
```

or by adding `display: block;` to the `redBackground` class in the below example (which is nasty though):

```html
<h:panelGrid column="2">
    <h:outputText value="some" styleClass="redBackground" />
    <h:inputTextarea />
</h:panelGrid>
```

The padding is irrelevant in this context. Your concrete problem was just that the background color was been set on the wrong element.